# Pull large data from the database using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

I am looking for any advice regarding the best practice when pulling large data from the database using PHP annd ORACLE db and calling it using an AJAX function (jQuery or React).

I have a large dataset (about ~ 2 million row) and I am required to pull at least 30% of it all the time.

The data request is called using a front-end written in simple Javascript that utilizes the AJAX function.

I'm simply just using the "traditional" way of pulling data. 
No prefetching,binding queries or stored procedure. just simply parsing the data. (i.e `Select * from sample_table where id='123';`

Every time I tried to pull certain amounts of data. The browser crashes.

Comment: _"I am required to pull at least 30% of it all the time."_ Er... what? You have to send 600K rows to the browser for each request?

Comment: What is the requirement specifically that requires you to pull ~700k rows at a time? This seems like the UI need to be rethought. One quick thing you could do is to make sure the table is well indexed (ie there's an index on the userId column). 

If you're calculating a value, it would be much faster to do it at the database level as opposed to crunching the numbers in PHP.

Comment: @AlexHowansky No. Actually this happens all the time the users wanted large data set for analysis. I think I miss quote myself here. I wanted to download that 300k-500k rows as CSV or TSV. My browser crashes if the data is <=3k.

Comment: @colefner Believe or not our users tend to request this huge amounts of rows. I think I may have explained it incorrectly. I wanted to be able to download at least 30% of that ~ 2 million rows as CSV but my browser crashes if the data is less than or approximately 3k.


I'm actually working on a passed project from a different team.  I wanted to work on what they have instead of rebuilding it because It might take years to do that but anyways, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ah ha! Ok, in that case, you probably don't want to do it as an AJAX request, just hit your download link directly in the browser. Is the data the same for everybody that downloads it? If so, maybe you could generate a compressed CSV file on the server from a cron script that runs every however often you need it to run, and then offer a download link to the already existing file. You can build a csv inside a zip on the fly with PHP compression streams.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I thought about that as well but the sad thing is that sometimes the request aren't the same at all. Some request are just under 1k dataset, some needed 100k and sometimes the data between the two request are not exactly alike.

Comment: @LexDacs You could store the request as a job (have a separate table for this) and have a cron run over the jobs on an interval. Then email the report to the user. Or email them a notification that the report is complete with a download link, depending on the sensitivity of the data.

Comment: That's a neat Idea. I could also try to use stored procedure and will be called using cron. 

Thanks!!

Comment: On the SQL side.  Don't forget to use bind variables instead of using string concatenation to build up your SQL statements.  Check the PHP OCI8 doc or the [Underground PHP & Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html)